# Web Site version control with Team Foundation System

Tags: web-applications, version-control, tfs, vs-web-site-project

We have a Web Site Project, (not a Web Application), and we need a way to track version changes on web pages. The .dlls are no problem, the problem is keeping track of the current version of a web page in the production server.

Is there a way to do this with TFS? I was thinking maybe a plugin the automatically placed some commented code physically on each modified web page indicating a version number and last modified date, for example. But I am really at a lost here.

I know one alternative would be to change the project type to Web Application, however, it's a big app and that would be a big project involving a lot of testing.

**EDIT:** What I ultimately need:

I need a way to identify the version of a web page on the production server. Like I said this is simple with dlls because they carry their version, but web pages don't have any versioning on the file itself. So that we can check the production server, look at a file and know which version it is.

Comment: Are you intending on versioning your web site with TFS, or you want the content of your web pages to reflect its version (i.e. visible in the HTML)?

Comment: @p.campbell The web site project is in TFS. My ultimate goal is to be able to identify the version of any web page on the production server. see question for edit...

Comment: How can you not _know_ the exact version of everything on your Production system? TFS won't fix bad process for you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders because we are not in control of the production server... We want to be able to audit this, and make sure those in control are doing the process correctly and when something doesn't work, they are using the current version that we provided for them. Maybe you could either provide helpful feedback rather than critize and judge a situation you know nothing about.

Comment: The only assumption I made is that you and the owners of the production server were the same company at least. If these are external customers, then you should have said so. It then becomes the case that you need to know what you shipped to your customers, and if you have customers who change things, you can then compare against what you shipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my co-workers solved this problem by building a Visual Studio Addin which shows all the changed web page files and gives you the option to set the next version or define one yourself and write it to the file.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Why is it that every time I show good manners, some one comes and edit them out?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts. This is not a discussion forum, we are not having a conversation, and your manners are misplaced in these circumstances.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I guess if its a site policy then I get it. I just think that sometimes a thank you actually goes a long way, even more than "points" added. But thank you for directing me to that post, I'll keep my manners out of SO from now on. I mean, that was the last time just now, jeje...

Comment: The site is community-driven. That means that you get a say, too. But the consensus (131 upvotes at this moment) is to remove those. [so] is a unique sort of site, strictly Q&A, and "thanks" is neither part of a Q nor an A. We don't do much "what do you think", or "list of X", either. It takes some getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/07/versioning-builds-with-tfs-and-msbuild.html) explaining how this can be done (with a link to a TFS 2010 version).

At the core it involves creating a version.txt file with the build number in it and making this information visible on the site.  If you want to hardcode this into every page, you could  tweak the process to embed that version.txt in the HTML of each and every page isntead.